# Problem with importing Firebase into Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

After following the steps, i could deal with error of "import Firebase" to my AppDelegate, but still can not configure firebase in my code!

I already created a firebase account and downloaded 'GoogleService-Info.plist' and added it to my project and also used 'pod init', edited it to add Firebase Core, Auth, Database' and 'pod install' to create xcworkspace. 
However after using 'import Firebase' in my AppDelegate, i received an error of 'Could not build Objective-C module Firebase'. I changed the product/scheme to 'Firebase' and the error was gone but still Firebase is not recognizable inside my code to be configured.

I would be so thankful for any clue!

Comment: Can you share the git real quick so I can take a quick look?

Comment: Im almost new to git. how can i do that?!

Comment: Can you share an online link with your code then?

Comment: Here's the link of my project:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/76hthr0ac04fqv9/FireApp.zip/file
I appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the AppDelegate.swift file, add `FirebaseApp.configure()` and make sure to delete. If you get the arm errors, make sure to stat a new project from scratch and add Firebase podfiles again. It should work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199392/discussion-on-answer-by-iss-problem-with-importing-firebase-into-xcode-project).

Answer (score 1):

[image: structure]

open project use .xcworkspace file, when use pod install framework

Comment: I started from scratch several times and still the same. I beleive there is a problem with importing Firebase in app delegate. I get the error "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' " and i think changing the scheme is just a temporary solution to deal with error and Firebase has not yet properly been imported.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have open project use xcworkspace

Comment: This would be a comment not an answer.